# Having issues creating a struct for this JSON

Tags: json, go

I am very, very new to golang (using this project as a way to learn the language better). I have an api I'd like to pull data from, but I can't seem to create the right type of struct for it.

The full JSON I am trying to encode is located here. https://prices.runescape.wiki/api/v1/osrs/latest

The structure of the JSON is

```
{
  "data": {
    "2": {
      "high": 182,
      "highTime": 1621811749,
      "low": 180,
      "lowTime": 1621811755
    },
    "6": {
      "high": 186683,
      "highTime": 1621811083,
      "low": 184528,
      "lowTime": 1621811286
    },
    ... REPEATS THOUSANDS OF TIMES ...
  }
}
```

I have tried using the [JSON to Go](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/) converter for the JSON data, but that returns a struct that is entirely too large. (Go returns an error) I have tried to manually make a struct with a slice as follows

```
type osrsPrices []struct {
    ID struct {
        High     int `json:"high"`
        Hightime int `json:"highTime"`
        Low      int `json:"low"`
        Lowtime  int `json:"lowTime"`
    } `json:"id"`
}
```

Whenever I try to run this from the terminal I am presented with the error **"json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type main.osrsPrices exit status 1"**

Here is the entire code I am using

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

type osrsPrices []struct {
    ID struct {
        High     int `json:"high"`
        Hightime int `json:"highTime"`
        Low      int `json:"low"`
        Lowtime  int `json:"lowTime"`
    } `json:"id"`
}

func main() {
    url := "https://prices.runescape.wiki/api/v1/osrs/latest"

    spaceClient := http.Client{
        Timeout: time.Second * 2, // Timeout after 2 seconds
    }

    req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "skillerscape:LearningGoLang|priceChecker")

    res, getErr := spaceClient.Do(req)
    if getErr != nil {
        log.Fatal(getErr)
    }

    if res.Body != nil {
        defer res.Body.Close()
    }

    body, readErr := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if readErr != nil {
        log.Fatal(readErr)
    }

    items := osrsPrices{}
    jsonErr := json.Unmarshal(body, &items)
    if jsonErr != nil {
        log.Fatal(jsonErr)
    }

    for _, item := range items {
        fmt.Println(item)
    }

}
```

I am pretty sure the error has to do with the way I am trying to process the data, but I cannot figure out the issue directly, nor the solution despite a couple hours of googling. I appreciate any help anyone has on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the deepest level, you have:

```
type Price struct {
   High     int `json:"high"`
   Hightime int `json:"highTime"`
   Low      int `json:"low"`
   Lowtime  int `json:"lowTime"`
}
```

This is in an object with variable keys, so you need:

```
type Data struct {
   Data map[string]Price `json:"data"`
}
```

Then you can unmarshal into an instance of this struct:

```
var data Data
json.Unmarshal(input,&data)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have successfully pulled the data with your help. Now I can actually work with it :).

Comment: Do you have any pointers on how I can iterate over the data? Whenever I try I get an error stating "data[0] (type Data does not support indexing)" The "type Data" part is where I think I am getting extra lost.

Comment: `data.Data["2"]` would be the right way to get to an element. Read the Tour of Go and other tutorials, you seem to lack the basics.

Comment: I thought I had enough to do a little testing around with the language, but clearly I have some more learning to do. That last tidbit helps me for now though. Thanks!